# Taking power as the writing of 2^2 in C

Tags: c, loops

I am coding a program that calculates the primes of the number which is entered. I created a program that finds the primes but I want to write the same values as power.

```
if (num < 0)
    printf("THIS VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE TO FIND THE PRIMES");
else {
    x = 2;
    while (num != 0) {
        if (num % x != 0)
            x = x + 1;
        else {
            num = num / x;
            printf("%d", x);

            if (num == 1)
                break;
```

in here for example when I enter 9 it gives 3 3 and I want to see it as 3^2. I would be appreciate if you answer.

Comment: So what have you tried doing to achieve that?

Comment: I tried to add a new if loop to count the numbers.But I failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just count the number of times you can divide by a given prime candidate and print the exponent form if the count is greater than 1.
Here is how it works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void factor(int num) {
    unsigned int n, x, count;
    int sep = '=';

    if (num < 0) {
        printf("Cannot handle negative number %d\n", num);
        return;
    }
    printf("%d", num);
    for (n = num, x = 2; x * x <= n; x++) {
        for (count = 0; n % x == 0; count++) {
            n /= x;
        }
        if (count >= 1) {
            printf(" %c %u", sep, x);
            sep = '*';
            if (count > 1) {
                printf("^%u", count);
            }
        }
    }
    if (n > 1 || n == num) {
        printf(" %c %u", sep, n);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        factor(i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        factor((1U << i) - 1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- I used `unsigned` arithmetics to avoid overflow when trying to factor `2147483647` (2<sup>31</sup>-1) which happens to be a [Mersenne Prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime).
- There is a potential undefined behavior in the `main` function if type `int` has less than 32 bits.
- The scan can be made twice as fast by changing the `x++` into `x += 1 + (x & 1)` to skip even numbers greater than 2.